# Vector drawable not drawn correctly in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, android-vectordrawable, sketch-3

I'm in the middle of a redesign for an app, and I am having problems with getting some of the icons to draw correctly in Android Studio. I'm using Sketch for all of the design work.

I've looked around quite a bit online to try and figure out a solution but am having a very difficult explaining the problem with search terms, so I thought I would try posting screenshots and providing a Sketch file to see if the StackOverflow community can help.

I think the problem has to do with the construction of my vector paths in Sketch, in particular with how they overlap one another. Here is an example of an icon I'm working on:

[Earth shape with longitude and latitude lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnzkQ.png)

As you can see, I have no problems creating the icon in Sketch. However, after I export the icon to an SVG file, and import it into Android Studio, here is how it is getting drawn:

[Icon drawn in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9r2m.png)

I only run into this problem when the shapes get more complex and start overlapping one another. Until now, I have been able to keep things simple for most icons, but it's getting to the point where I need to find a solution.

I was going to post a link to the Sketch file in Dropbox, but I need more reputation points to do that. If needed, hopefully I can provide that link to someone in a response.

Any help would be much appreciated. If this is a duplicate question, I apologize. In all of my searching, I may not have worded the issue in such a way to get good results.

@Paul LeBeau, thank you for the response. Here is the SVG code exported from Sketch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.8.3 (29802) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>globe</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="globe" fill="#368EFA">
            <g id="test" transform="translate(2.000000, 2.000000)">
                <path d="M1.76297407,13 L5.00480805,13 C4.73881764,12.1144772 4.55303608,11.1138143 4.50968627,10 L1.02773406,10 C1.01839018,9.83680058 1.01365419,9.67236691 1.01365419,9.5068271 C1.01365419,9.33666963 1.01865808,9.16768089 1.02852674,9 L4.50968627,9 C4.55303608,7.88618573 4.73881764,6.8855228 5.00480805,6 L1.76915759,6 C1.92639337,5.65361668 2.10620446,5.31965722 2.30671248,5 L5.35559719,5 C6.20744032,2.88601313 7.45296691,1.59423095 7.91693127,1.16221702 C8.43195688,1.06468547 8.96343249,1.01365419 9.5068271,1.01365419 C10.0442032,1.01365419 10.569923,1.06356132 11.0796041,1.15899346 C11.5408038,1.58777803 12.7904304,2.88072886 13.6444028,5 L16.7069417,5 C16.9074497,5.31965722 17.0872608,5.65361668 17.2444966,6 L13.9951919,6 C14.2611824,6.8855228 14.4469639,7.88618573 14.4903137,9 L17.9851275,9 C17.9949961,9.16768089 18,9.33666963 18,9.5068271 C18,9.67236691 17.995264,9.83680058 17.9859201,10 L14.4903137,10 C14.4469639,11.1138143 14.2611824,12.1144772 13.9951919,13 L17.2506801,13 C17.0942093,13.3463294 16.915188,13.6802868 16.7154884,14 L13.6444028,14 C12.7787643,16.1482222 11.506588,17.4473934 11.0611474,17.8580954 C10.5572344,17.95129 10.0377192,18 9.5068271,18 C8.96992723,18 8.44466314,17.9501813 7.93540532,17.8549144 C7.4868821,17.4407166 6.21901315,16.1427067 5.35559719,14 L2.29816579,14 C2.09846621,13.6802868 1.9194449,13.3463294 1.76297407,13 Z M6.02760136,13 L9,13 L9,10 L5.51031179,10 C5.55606369,11.1058076 5.7507371,12.108186 6.02760136,13 Z M6.38814497,14 L9,14 L9,17.9088258 C8.62776002,17.558389 7.2971495,16.2062617 6.38814497,14 Z M9,1.09117415 L9,5 L6.38814497,5 C7.2971495,2.79373835 8.62776002,1.44161098 9,1.09117415 Z M6.02760136,6 L9,6 L9,9 L5.51031179,9 C5.55606369,7.8941924 5.7507371,6.89181397 6.02760136,6 Z M10,13 L12.9723986,13 C13.2492629,12.108186 13.4439363,11.1058076 13.4896882,10 L10,10 L10,13 Z M10,14 L12.611855,14 C11.7028505,16.2062617 10.37224,17.558389 10,17.9088258 L10,14 Z M10,1.09117415 C10.37224,1.44161098 11.7028505,2.79373835 12.611855,5 L10,5 L10,1.09117415 Z M10,6 L12.9723986,6 C13.2492629,6.89181397 13.4439363,7.8941924 13.4896882,9 L10,9 L10,6 Z" id="earth"></path>
                <path d="M9.5,18 L9.5,18 C14.1944204,18 18,14.1944204 18,9.5 C18,4.80557963 14.1944204,1 9.5,1 C4.80557963,1 1,4.80557963 1,9.5 C1,14.1944204 4.80557963,18 9.5,18 L9.5,18 Z M9.5,19 L9.5,19 C4.25329488,19 0,14.7467051 0,9.5 C0,4.25329488 4.25329488,0 9.5,0 C14.7467051,0 19,4.25329488 19,9.5 C19,14.7467051 14.7467051,19 9.5,19 L9.5,19 Z" id="border"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the code after importing the SVG file directly into Android Studio:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M3.763,15L7.005,15C6.739,14.114 6.553,13.114 6.51,12L3.028,12C3.018,11.837 3.014,11.672 3.014,11.507C3.014,11.337 3.019,11.168 3.029,11L6.51,11C6.553,9.886 6.739,8.886 7.005,8L3.769,8C3.926,7.654 4.106,7.32 4.307,7L7.356,7C8.207,4.886 9.453,3.594 9.917,3.162C10.432,3.065 10.963,3.014 11.507,3.014C12.044,3.014 12.57,3.064 13.08,3.159C13.541,3.588 14.79,4.881 15.644,7L18.707,7C18.907,7.32 19.087,7.654 19.244,8L15.995,8C16.261,8.886 16.447,9.886 16.49,11L19.985,11C19.995,11.168 20,11.337 20,11.507C20,11.672 19.995,11.837 19.986,12L16.49,12C16.447,13.114 16.261,14.114 15.995,15L19.251,15C19.094,15.346 18.915,15.68 18.715,16L15.644,16C14.779,18.148 13.507,19.447 13.061,19.858C12.557,19.951 12.038,20 11.507,20C10.97,20 10.445,19.95 9.935,19.855C9.487,19.441 8.219,18.143 7.356,16L4.298,16C4.098,15.68 3.919,15.346 3.763,15ZM8.028,15L11,15L11,12L7.51,12C7.556,13.106 7.751,14.108 8.028,15ZM8.388,16L11,16L11,19.909C10.628,19.558 9.297,18.206 8.388,16ZM11,3.091L11,7L8.388,7C9.297,4.794 10.628,3.442 11,3.091ZM8.028,8L11,8L11,11L7.51,11C7.556,9.894 7.751,8.892 8.028,8ZM12,15L14.972,15C15.249,14.108 15.444,13.106 15.49,12L12,12L12,15ZM12,16L14.612,16C13.703,18.206 12.372,19.558 12,19.909L12,16ZM12,3.091C12.372,3.442 13.703,4.794 14.612,7L12,7L12,3.091ZM12,8L14.972,8C15.249,8.892 15.444,9.894 15.49,11L12,11L12,8Z"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:fillColor="#368EFA"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M11.5,20L11.5,20C16.194,20 20,16.194 20,11.5C20,6.806 16.194,3 11.5,3C6.806,3 3,6.806 3,11.5C3,16.194 6.806,20 11.5,20L11.5,20ZM11.5,21L11.5,21C6.253,21 2,16.747 2,11.5C2,6.253 6.253,2 11.5,2C16.747,2 21,6.253 21,11.5C21,16.747 16.747,21 11.5,21L11.5,21Z"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:fillColor="#368EFA"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
```

Comment: Can you paste the SVG as code in your question please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your icon is a circle with 16 holes cut out of it. Is that correct?

If so, it's probably an issue with the fill rule.  VectorDrawables (and SVGs) use a non-zero fill rule by default, which will give different results if your shape is rendered using the even-odd fill rule.

I am guessing that Sketch defaults to using the even-odd fill rule.  Or perhaps you changed it to even-odd (?)

If for some reason you can't fix the fill rule in Sketch, or it doesn't get passed through when you convert to a VectorDrawable, you will need to manually change it yourself in the VectorDrawable.

Open the VectorDrawable file and find the `<path>` element. Then change (or set) the following attribute:

```
android:fillType="evenodd"
```

**Update**

Okay I thought that switching the fillType would work, but it doesn't.  But I do have a fix.

What many people don't know is that the segment draw direction of filled paths has an affect on fill.  By segment draw direction, I mean whether the points in the path (or subpath) were drawn in a clockwise, or anticlockwise, direction.  This is known as the "winding" of the points.

Modify your file and alter the six faulty subpaths (cutouts) so that they are drawn in the opposite direction to what they are now. Your VectorDrawable should render correctly then.

For example, if you try this modified VectorDrawable file, you'll see that I've rearranged the points in one of the cut-outs (the top left faulty one) to the opposite winding direction.  Some vector editors can reverse the path direction for you. I'm not sure if Sketch can.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you very much for your response. The shape isn't a circle with 16 cutouts. Instead, I used six 1px rectangles to create the divisions within the circle. I added the SVG code to my original post, and here is link to the Sketch file in Dropbox if that would be helpful: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3wvzqfb9xecy5w/globe.sketch?dl=0>  I tried finding information about Sketch's fill type for SVGs, but I couldn't find anything online. I did try adding the {android:fillType="evenodd"} attribute to the '<path>' element in Android Studio, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Hey Paul...that pretty much took care of the issue. I say pretty much because I had to flatten the overarching path prior to reversing the drawing order of the subpaths. The way I constructed the graphic may be a little funky, but I'm just getting used to building shapes with vector tools...much better with Photoshop but getting away from raster graphics. At any rate, thank you VERY much for your help! As I get better with creating my shapes, I think the answer you provided will help a ton.

Comment: fillType seems to have changed from evenodd to evenOdd some time in the last years. couldn't edit as "Suggested edit queue is full". thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem too, three of my icons doesn't render properly in Android Studio.

While the root cause is VectorDrawable doesn't support even-odd fillType, to make it work you shouldn't edit it on the .svg files. You must edit it on Sketch itself. [This article](https://medium.com/@dineshbob10/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452) explain thoroughly about this topic. I'll try to recap some of the main point.

1. In Sketch. Find your missing shape. In my case, it was a circle shape.

[image: Missing Shape]

2. On Fills configuration (Gear shaped icon), change it to Non-Zero.

[image: Fills configuration]

3. You need to readjust your shape order, open Layer -> Paths -> Reverse Order.

[image: Reverse Order]

4. Export your Grouped shape.

[image: Export from Sketch]

5. Convert it to VectorDrawable (via Android Studio or 3rd party tools).

Sometimes I need to repeat step 3. Nevertheless, it always works in my case. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I had no idea the option for "Non-Zero / Even-Odd" existed in the Fill settings @aldok! I haven't got a chance to use it yet, but I will keep this in mind as we I run into other problems exporting graphics.

Answer (score -1):

just override material design scaling on top.
on top right corner.