# SVG icon from Sketch is corrupted

Tags: svg, sketchapp

I have icon in Sketch, but when I export it to SVG, it's somehow corrupted. I have no idea why and how to solve that. Can you help me?

Result: [image]

Source: http://test.marekcernak.cz/leave.sketch

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, just something you'd report to Sketch's bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

Redraw your leaf design to avoid paths that overlap themselves.

I don't use Sketch, but there have been similar questions relating to Sketch and issues it has regarding incompatible support for `fill-rule` (a.k.a. winding rule).  For example [see this this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154187/vector-drawable-not-drawn-correctly-in-android-studio).

If you fix the overlaps, I believe you should have much better results when you export to SVG.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have style collision with other SVGs that you have exported to use in the same page. Make sure you use unique names for `id` and `class` attributes.